# Возможно ли в односвязном списке сделать ввод/удаление элементов в конец/из конца списка?

Tags: c, list, структуры, односвязный-список

Я знаю (но пока не понял реализацию), что с помощью двух указателей (то есть реализовать уже двусвязный список) сделать ввод/удаление элементов в конец/из конца списка возможно.

Но как это сделать в односвязном списке **БЕЗ перебора элементов в поисках конца списка**(условие задачи)? Если все же сделать без двух указателей это невозможно, то сильно ли изменится оставшийся код программы? Удалось сделать эти действия только в начало списка:

```
struct person
{
    char secondname[30];
    int math, rus, eng;
};
typedef struct person DataType;
struct node
{
    DataType data;
    struct node* head;
    //struct node* tail;
    struct node* next;
}
.....
list new_node(list begin, DataType person)
{
    list temp = (list)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = person;
    temp->next = begin;
    return temp;
}
.....
list delete_node(list begin)
{
    system("CLS");
    struct node* temp;
    if (begin)
    {
        temp = begin;
        begin = begin->next;
        free(temp);
        puts("Удалено");
        system("pause");
    }
    return begin;
}
```

Comment: Используйте вот такие структуры для заголовка списка `struct list { struct list_elem *first, *last;};` и элемента списка `struct list_elem { DataType data; struct list_elem *next;};`, далее правильным образом обновляйте эти указатели при изменении списка.

Comment: не сильно, в два раза. Четыре указателя поменять. При добавлении элемента нужно поменять указатель следующего у предыдущего, предыдущего у следующего и два указателя у нового. `A<->New<->B`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно хранить адрес последнего узла, но для его получения придётся всё равно хоть раз список пробежать.

И постоянно заботиться об его актуальности: добавили в конец - обновили `last`

P.S.
Однако удаление последнего узла всё равно потребует поиска предыдущего проходом с начала.

Comment: то есть добавить еще один указатель в структуру node, и уже для нее создать функцию, которая единожды пробежит весь список для поиска последнего?

Comment: В структуру не надо - отдельный node держать. Функцию поиска конца можно сделать, если список неизвестно откуда появляется, а не вами заполняется. Иначе при создании первого узла begin и end на один узел указывают, а потом уже расходятся.

Comment: Удалению из конца это не поможет.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Мда, про удаление я и забыл.